# Custom DataGridView column - where am I going wrong?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to create a new DataGridView column type that allows the following:

- Multiple small thumbnails of images, split to multiple lines if need
  be
- The ability to hover or click over each thumbnail, which will display the full size image
- The ability to drag a thumbnail from one row to another row

Taking one step at a time, I'm trying to get it to at least display the images correctly. Here is my code for the Column:

```
public class DataGridViewPODColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewPODColumn()
    {
         this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewPODCell();
    }

    public override object Clone()
    {
         return base.Clone()
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the cell:

```
public class DataGridViewPODCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    private static Type defaultValueType = typeof(List<PODImage>);
    private int _XCoordinate = 0;
    private int _YCoordinate = 0;

    public int XCoordinate { get { return _XCoordinate; } set { _XCoordinate = value; } }
    public int YCoordinate { get { return _YCoordinate; } set { _YCoordinate = value; } }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            Type valueType = base.ValueType;
            if (valueType != null) return valueType;
            return defaultValueType;
        }
    }

    protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {

        if (this.DataGridView == null) return;
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (PODImage podVal in (List<PODImage>)value)
        {
            GraphicsContainer container = graphics.BeginContainer();
            graphics.SetClip(cellBounds);
            Point objPoint = new Point(cellBounds.Location.X + XCoordinate, cellBounds.Location.Y + YCoordinate);
            graphics.DrawImage(podVal.POD, objPoint.X, objPoint.Y, 20, 40);
            XCoordinate += 22;
            counter++;
            if (counter % 3 == 0)
            {
                YCoordinate += 42;
                XCoordinate = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I have some major issues with this:

1. I can't add my column via the DGV designer - when I choose that type for a column and click 'Add', it just doesn't add the column, so I have to do it in the code
2. Most of the row turns black, and clicking an image causes it to move to the right (i.e. it seems to think it's a new image)
3. The word 'Collection' is displayed behind the images

I know this is probably fairly basic stuff! I'm new to Windows Forms development, having worked only in ASP.NET the past year...oh how I long for my GridView and TemplateField's!

If anyone can point me in the right direction here I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I'm going to have a proper look at your question when I have a minute spare in the next couple of days but thought I'd suggest that if possible, use WPF - the things you want to do are very easy with the WPF grids.